# magento2 check record exist in my custom method from observer

Tags: magento2

In my magento 1.x, there is a function in my observer which checks if there is a product in my custom table, something like this:

```
class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer
{
  protected $_queue;

  function __construct()
  {
     $this->_queue = Mage::getModel('sync/queue');
  }

  public function productUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer).
  {
     //Check already record is exists in queue table
     $existingProduct = $this->_queue->load($product_id,'product_id');
  }
```

I want to achieve the same thing in Magento 2.x, i.e. call the `getModel()` and use the '_queue' in the `productUpdate()`.

How do I use this?

In my **magento 2.x** observer, I am calling like:

```
function __construct
(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Engine $syncEngineFactory      
)
{   
    $this->syncEngineFactory = $syncEngineFactory;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $this->syncEngineFactory->productUpdate($observer);
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

In Model\Engine:

```
public function __construct(
\Vendor\Module\Model\Queue $_queue,

array $data = []
) {

   $this->_queue=$_queue;
);
}
```

Where my Model/Queue calls the ResourceModel Queue in the constructor as

```
$this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue');
```

How do I use the **'_queue'** in my `\Vendor\Module\Model\Engine`?

Comment: Thanks, solved it as :  In my model engines constructor, \Vendor\Module\Model\Queue $_queue, array $data = []
    ) {$this->_queue=$_queue;

Comment: To answer your own question, it would be good to add a new answer. please don't add answer in your question.

Comment: Ok Mohit, thought it would help others whit same issue so added the answer

Answer (score 2):

> How do I use the '_queue' in my \Vendor\Module\Model\Engine?

You can try to load the model by

```
function __construct
(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Engine $myQueueModel
)
{   
    $this->_queue = $myQueueModel;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

$queueModel = $this->_queue->create();
// Load the item with ID is 1
$item =  $this->_queue->load($Id);
var_dump($item->getData());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: See the updated ans

Comment: In execute() i just called my custom(), which is working...i have a doubt in this ...http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127208/magento-call-mutiple-methods-in-observers-execute where can i call multiple methods ?